# WCF vs Service Bus

Tags: c#, wcf, nservicebus

We're in a tight spot at work and I need some clarity:

> **Basically:** We can use WCF to read/write to an MSMQ and get type
>   safety on the objects we pass.
>
> **Alternative:** We could use something like NService Bus to do the
>   exact same thing.

Now at my work we're all well versed in WCF, but none of us are well versed in using a Service Bus.

So could someone please help me with some pros/cons gains/losses for using WCF or NService Bus as right now it looks to me that it would be easier to use WCF (as long as we don't need advanced transactions etc)?

How easy would you estimate it would be to later change from WCF to NService Bus?

Kind regards

Comment: pro you know alot about WCF, con you know little about NService bus. Period.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on what kind of processing you are doing beyond getting objects on to the queue?  This would help to determine if NSB is for you.

Comment: After a lot of investigation, testing and analysis we arrived at the conclusion that a ServiceBus was the way to go. We have a lot of events (a trading system) and want to have good separation of responsibilities in our system. That said I agree with Roy and Eric, NSB have not been that easy to get started with, however it HAVE ensured that we had to think hard about how we were doing things (ex. which kind of NSB messages should carry data). This among a lot of other things I believe was a big benefit for us, since it made a lot of unexpected issues surface really quick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is push messages into MSMQ, you don't need either.

NServiceBus doesn't just enqueue messages. Per NServiceBus service that you write, you can specify to which messages it subscribes and which it publishes. NServiceBus then takes care of the dispatching and delivering of the messages, using MSMQ as the transport mechanism.

NServiceBus makes it easy this way for applications to just publish and subscribe to messages without requiring knowledge of where they come from, or when a service has moved to another server.

However, NServiceBus is not as easy to use as you might think, there is not a lot of good documentation available. It thus takes some time to plough through it.

And since v2.5, you need a commercial license if you want to use it on more than one thread.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, I wouldn't use NServiceBus as a way to simply get messages onto a queue. As Roy says, NServiceBus is not trivial to implement. It's an architectural choice, not simply an implementation choice.

However, when my team moved from a WCF solution to NServiceBus, we were very happy (after the learning curve). One of the advantages is that the design of the system makes it harder to do the wrong thing. That is to say, if something is hard to do in NServiceBus, then you are probably not thinking about the architecture the way you should (if you want an asynchronous,  scalable, maintainable system).